# What is the difference between date format “2019-06-17-04:00” and “2019-06-17Z”? exactly what time does “2019-06-17Z” point to?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, openshift

I’m using `XMLGregorianCalendar` in my spring boot app to define a date range and using the same in the input while calling an REST service.  However, when I’m calling the service from my local, I see the date is being set as “2019-06-17-04:00” in the REST input XML. If I run the same app in Openshift container, the date is being set as “2019-06-17Z” in the request XML. Can you please let me know the reason for this? And what is the difference between these two date formats?

```
XMLGregorianCalendar toDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
XMLGregorianCalendar fromDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(<some date>);
```

Comment: One is a timestamp with date + time, the other is just a date. Is that what you ask?

Comment: Is there a “T” in the -04:00 one?  At, say, 22:00 (10:00 PM) US/Eastern time, it could be 2019-06-17T-04:00, but at the same instant it would be 2019-06-18Z in UTC.

Comment: No. there is no "T" in the time. exactly what time does “2019-06-17Z” point to?

Comment: “2019-06-17Z” is presumably intended to mean “2019-06-17T00:00:00Z”, i.e., the very first instant of June 17th 2019, as measured in UTC.  Whether it's standard-conformant I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

The suffix on both inputs refer to offset-from-UTC, presumably.

- The `-04:00` on `2019-06-17-04:00` means four hours behind UTC.
- the `Z` on `2019-06-17Z` means zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC, that is, UTC itself. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu” and is short for `+00:00:00`.

However, both of **your inputs are meaningless**. Assigning an offset to a date without a time-of-day makes no sense. Indeed, on some days such as a Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutover, a date might involve two offsets.

You should report these values to the publisher as erroneous. Educate them about the ISO 8691 standard for reporting date-time values.